# Is it possible to download builds from the app store?

Tags: ios, cordova

Hi I lost the cordova project folder and I no longer have the html and javscript files.
My latest build is currently on my App store.
Can I download the latest build and get the files inside?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to install the app on your iphone.
Then open xcode and safari.
In safari dev tools inspect your phone connected to your Mac.

Then you can save HTML, JS and CSS files.
After that you create a new project in your console, install plugins.
Then copy paste your HTML, JS and CSS files into the folder www inside platforms/ios/

Comment: it's possible if it is debug app.